# How Do You Cut the Maximum Volume Cuboid from a General 3D Shape?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I would like to find a way to cut the maximum cuboid slab out of 3D crystalline structures. For example, say I have some 3D convex polyhedral shape, how would I go about finding the maximum cuboid that could be enclosed by that shape? With the extra limiting factor that the cuboid edges must be parallel to the x, y, z axes.

I am unaware of any algorithm for solving this problem in 2D or 3D.

Currently I am thinking of dividing the space into cubes and slowly expanding the cube surface in each direction around a central point until I can't expand anymore in each direction. Would this be an appropriate method?

Is there a general method I am unaware of? Ideally it should be possible to port the method to a computer. A 2D example of the 3D problem is given below:

[image: 2D crystal plane with rough estimate of maximum inscribable rectangle]

Each point represents an atom in a crystal plane, and the blue rectangle represents and estimate of the maximum inscribable rectangle. Ideally I would like an algorithmic way to define the blue box. In 3D the blue box would be represented by a cuboid instead.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify. Show us some pictures. Must the cuboid have edges parallel to the axes? Is the 3D shape convex? Connected? Can you answer the question for a 2D shape? Where does the question come from? Are you looking for an algorithm you could implement on a computer?

Comment: Are you asking about the sort-of opposite of the ["bounding box"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms) problem? i.e. the volume of the largest box that is contained completely within a given region

Comment: How is your shape specified? When you say "crystalline" you suggest that the shape is polyhedral. Do you have equations for its boundary? Is it a set of points from which you form the convex hull? Please show us some pictures for the two dimensional version of the problem.

Comment: @EthanBolker The shape is polyhedral yes, sorry I'll add that too. It is a set of points around which I can form a convex hull.

Comment: Search for "largest rectangle in a polygon". This problem has been studied in the plane. That work might get you started, or leave you frustrated. First hit: https://www.evryway.com/largest-interior/ And see http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks so much, if you write up something along similar lines into an answer I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search for [largest rectangle in a polygon](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=largest%20rectangle%20in%20a%20polygon) shows that this problem has been studied in the plane.

[Here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eathens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/) is a solution that would find the rectangle in your illustration (it's a computer science student project, well done and well documented).

I suspect the three dimensional problem is a fair bit harder.

(This link only answer posted at the OP's request.)